# DOMPDF not caching some fonts

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I want to use 5 different fonts in my PDF (all of them TrueType). Yesterday I added one of them as `@font-face` and copied the file to `/storage/fonts` (I am using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf, so this is set by default). The .ufm was created and added to `dompdf_font_family_cache.php`, everything worked fine.

Today I wanted to add the rest of the fonts, I have made separate `@font-face` properties, copied the fonts but no .ufm files were created, so they can't be used in the PDF.

**Google Fonts** can be added without any problem, and they are getting cached!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style>
            @page {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'font1';
                src: url('/storage/fonts/font1.ttf') format('truetype');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'font2';
                src: url('/storage/fonts/font2.ttf') format('truetype');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }
            .font1{
                text-align: center;
                font-family: 'font1', sans-serif;
            }
            .font2{
                font-family: 'font2', sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="font1">This font is cached</div>
            <div class="font2">This font isn't</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am on a local WAMP server (PHP 5.6.25), Laravel 5.3, DOMPDF 0.8 w/ laravel-dompdf.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all files in the `storage\fonts`

Give permission to DOMPDF to create fonts there

```
sudo chmod -R 755 storage/fonts
```

Create a new pdf to regenerate the fonts.

Comment: Okay, you put me on the right track. I deleted everything from the `/storage/fonts` directory, put the files in the `public` directory and called those URLs in the `@font-face`. All fonts are cached and ready, now I understand how it works. :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, Glad it helped you!

Comment: Hello @João, I tried this too, but new font which I have added is not cached in storage/fonts directory. I have put new font in public/fonts directory and included it in PDF view file and created a new PDF, but still it don't cache in storage. I am using laravel 5.5, can you please help me to sort this out.

Comment: Have you tried to put the fonts manually in the storage/fonts and regenerate the PDF?

Comment: You should try the comment above, or simple try to reference the font from some cdn. like this: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I tried to include a font by using this **src: url('{{url("/fonts/fireflysung.ttf")}}') format('truetype');** i.e. in public/fonts directory.
Yes I tried by using some external link like cdn or something else and it is working fine, but what should I do to use it as expected i.e it should generate cache files in storage/fonts  automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I did not use this plugin anymore, so, I don't know what to tell you. If you try to put the fonts in the public folder instead of storage folder and reference the fonts in blade template? Like this:

`src: url('{{ public_path('fonts/OptimusPrinceps.tff') }}');`

Check this answer to more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966953/where-do-i-place-custom-fonts-in-laravel-5

Comment: Another try is to check if the laravel can find the fireflysung fonts using the storage