# Laravel SCSS file can't cope with relative paths for @font-face

Tags: css, laravel, webpack

I'm working on an ".scss" file for a Laravel website. I'm trying to use a locally stored ".otf" font file in a CSS `@font-face` tag.

The problem is that Laravel / web pack doesn't seem to be able to cope with relative paths for CSS `src:` properties. However, I need it to because the directory structure is going to change from the current development environment to when it's deployed, so I'm avoiding hard coding the full path.

**The SCSS code:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: LucyScript;
    src: url('../fonts/LucyScript.otf');
}
```

**Error message (`npm run watch`):**
[image]

**Update:**

I've managed to put in a "workaround" by adding the following to my "app.blade.php" file:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: LucyScript;
        src: url('./fonts/LucyScript.otf');
    }
</style>
```

However, this isn't ideal as it's now mixing the CSS and HTML, if anyone knows how to resolve this just from within the ".scss" please enlighten me.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code looks fine and sass-loader is able to handle relative paths for sure. Are you sure that you have `LucyScript.otf` file in `resources/assets/fonts` directory?

Comment: `src: url('/fonts/LucyScript.otf');`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36967077/465560

Comment: Understood, your assets directory contains `js`,`sass`, `fonts` and you want your scss to use the relative path. But while building it might give error. I have tested in my project and it takes the path. Not sure about windows machine.

Comment: @Priya Aye maybe it's a problem with Windows.

Comment: You can check : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2771 , using `resolve-url`

Comment: @Flying I've tried moving it to `resources/assets/fonts` rather than just `/public/fonts/`, the problem is that the path it has generated is relative to the root of the server, whereas my Laravel installation is actually running on `<root>/GIT/<directoryname>/`, so it's trying to look for the font at `<root>/fonts/`. when it's actually at `<root>/GIT/<directoryname>/public/fonts/`..