# Fonts not found with font-face in Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, fonts

I am working on a Laravel website and for the first time I'm using font-face to load custom fonts. Unfortunately it's not working as expected.

I have my fonts located at `/public/fonts` and use the following code, based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966953/where-do-i-place-custom-fonts-in-laravel-5)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Miriam Libre;
  src: url("/fonts/MiriamLibre-Regular.tff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Whitney Book;
  src: url("/fonts/whitney-book-webfont.tff");
}

body {
  font-family: Whitney Book, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

label {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-family: Miriam Libre, serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: $text-dark;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}
```

However this isn't working, since I'm getting 404 errors. A screenshot of the directory below.

[image]

Anyone with some quick tips or a solution to this? Unfortunately I couldn't find any solution on StackOverflow.

**Edit**
Weird thing is, if I hit the path of one of the fonts it will actually download the font..

Comment: seems you css is in another folder in the same level.. try ../fonts/etc  or ./../fonts/etc

Comment: That's not working, I'll get an error on my compiling. This should work in theory, since the fonts are located at `domain.com/fonts/` and I am pointing to that.

Comment: You need to double check the location of the .tff files. Don't do this in a browser console, but go into your FTP. Because 404 just means, cannot find file, so incorrect path and 404 is never a lie :)

Comment: Well, the problem is that it's also not working on my local env. I am pretty sure that the files are located at `/public/fonts`, as you can see on my screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it with a `Laravel Mix` solution. I've added the following to my Mix config:

`Mix.copyDirectory('resources/fonts', 'public/fonts');`

And with that I can change the path to `../fonts/etc` like Joe Ydoan Rauzes mentioned because the fonts are now located both at `resources` and `public` directory. It will copy the directory of `fonts` in resources and place it in the `public` direcotry on every compilation.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8, based on the setup above:  `Mix.copyDirectory('resources/fonts', 'public/fonts')`, the font path needs to be referenced like this, from the root:

```css
src: url('/fonts/LatoLatin-Regular.woff2') format('woff2')
```

Not like this: `../fonts` otherwise you'll get errors for missing fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in linux environment. I had downloaded the fonts and copied it into public directory (css in css directory and fonts in fonts directory). By default user and group of that folder is current logged in users domain, we need to change the permision for that folder so that www-data can access it.

```
#change the fonts permission (inside public directory), use sudo if you have to
chmod -R www-data:www-data fonts/
chmod -R 775 fonts
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to convert your .ttf to different font formats

for #Deepest Possible Browser Support . Check here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Possible cause is using .ttf and not providing .woff file font for example.